# Is it possible to report on who liked a chatter post/feed?

Tags: chatter-feed

I am trying to report on who liked a certain chatter post.
On the object_feed - I only see 'LikeCount' only.
On a certain post in the community:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7XPWSA3
It's mentioned that it's not possible, since likecount is not linked to any userid, however, if I look on the chatter post, I will see:
[image]

Where can I report on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be accessible through *reporting* when creating report types. But, [FeedLike](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feedlike.htm) is where the data you're looking for is stored for likes on *posts* (not comments).

> Indicates that a user has liked a feed item. This object is available in API version 21.0 and later.
>
> **FeedLike records represent likes on posts and not likes on comments. Likes on comments can’t be queried via the API**. A FeedLike is a child object of an associated FeedItem, FeedTrackedChange, or object feed, such as AccountFeed.

You'll note, under "Usage", the following:

> You can't query FeedLike records directly. They can only be queried via the entity feed, such as AccountFeed.

As such, you have to query it via the `FeedItem` (or `AccountFeed`, etc) where `InsertedId` is the user who liked the post

`SELECT Id, (SELECT InsertedById,InsertedBy.Name FROM FeedLikes) FROM FeedItem`